# Bcrypt Not Saving Password?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, express, passport.js

For some reason when I try to hash and save a password the new password is not saved to the database? I'm using MongoDB, NodeJS, and passport to let the users change their password.

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  var SALT_FACTOR = 5;
console.log('trying to save the password')

  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  user.password = hash;
  next();
});
});
});
```

Posting the save:

```
app.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user, next) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
          return res.redirect('back');
        }


        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
        console.log('password' + user.password  + 'and the user is' + user)

  user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
      console.log('here')
       return res.redirect('back');
  } else { 
      console.log('here2')
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      done(err, user);
    });

  }
        });
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure it slightly. Move the User updating function in to the Model so you'd have a user.js file which is a bit like this (e.g. models/user.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        bcrypt: true
    }
    // more fields etc
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.updateUser = function(newUser, userId, callback) {
    if (newUser.password != "" && newUser.password != undefined) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password,10,function(err,hash){
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            var upsertData = newUser.toObject();
            delete upsertData._id;
            User.update({_id: userId}, upsertData, {upsert:true}, callback);
        });
    } else {
        var upsertData = newUser.toObject();
        delete upsertData._id;
        delete upsertData.password;
        User.update({_id: userId}, upsertData, {upsert:true}, callback);
    };
}
```

Then in your route / app file you can include the user model which I guess you're doing anyway (e.g. routes/user.js):

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```

and use it like this:

```
var newUser = new User({
    password: password,
    field: value,
    field: value,
    field: value etc
});
User.updateUser(newUser, userId, function(){
    // rest of your code
});
```

That way you've got a re-usable function which will update the user regardless of the number of fields you pass to it.

As an aside, your bcrypt use and mine are effectively the same. I.e.

```
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
```

is the same as:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
```

from their docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt